# Extracting link display text as well as href attribute with PHP 5

Tags: php, dom, hyperlink

```
$oldSetting = libxml_use_internal_errors( true );

libxml_clear_errors();
```

I have seen many examples on the web on how to extract the URLs from HTML with PHP 5's DOM functions, but I need to get the link text as well as the link. If I use the code below to extract the link `http://X.com` from the `href` attribute in the anchor tag `<a href="http://X.com">YYYYY</a>`, how do I get the corresponding "YYYYY" associated with it?

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHtmlFile($location);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($html);
$links = $xpath->query( '//a' );
foreach ( $links as $link )
{
$url_list[$i++] = $link->getAttribute( 'href' ) . "\n";
}
libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors( $oldSetting );
```

Answer (score 0):

DOMDocument() is slow as hell. Try [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or [`xml_parse_into_struct()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php) instead.